# How to get rid of this exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codexus/resources/ResourcesManager?

Tags: java, exception, jar, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I run my .jar file in the terminal and this exception came out, but I know my main has the package of that .jar which has the `ResourcesManager.class`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        com/codexus/resources/ResourcesManager
            at 
    com.codexus.uts.ui.launcher.UiLauncher.main(UiLauncher.java:139)
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codexus.resources.ResourcesManager
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Comment: this means your classpath doesn't point to this class, check your menifest file.

Comment: You can also check 1) whether yours jars are all on the classpath and 2) whether your jars contain the specified class by inspecting them as a zip file.

Comment: thanks @SachinGupta! It's running now. :) I just edit my menifest file then that's it. :)

Comment: @halfer I posted my solution below.

Comment: Thanks. We don't use [solved] title hacks here - just accepting your own solution, by clicking the tick mark when the system allows it, is fine.

Comment: ow thanks @halfer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the exact things that I do to solved it.

First, I just open the `MANIFEST.MF` (found in my `main.jar`, `META-INF` folder) in Notepad and second, I replaced **all** the `lib/sample.jar` into `./sample.jar` so my `main.jar` can have an access to all the jars and its classes that its depending on, that's it. Hope it helps...